# File geodatabase not fully loading in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase

I am very new to GIS. I have been trying to load a gdb file into QGIS, but one of the layers appears completely different from the description in the metadata. The data can be downloaded here. https://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/ofr20181088

The layer that doesn't work for me is called "Recent_2013_2017_Mining_Activity_Dataset". It's supposed to contain loads of points where mining activities take place in the Central African Republic, but the layer I get in QGIS is a grid consisting of tiny squares covering the whole country.

Would anyone mind having a look at this for me?

I really don't know what is causing this.

Comment: If you do indeed have a polygon layer, you can use the Centroids tool to convert it to a point layer. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277942/centroids-in-qgis-3-0-not-using-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the metadata, it looks like it's a polygon layer derived from a raster dataset.  The only attribute that looks relevant is "Count_".  In the layer properties, if you use a source-provider feature filter to only show `"Count_" > 0` then symbolize on `Count_`

[image]

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Solved it! That was really helpful!

Comment: If you don't mind me asking a follow-up question, the metadata says there should be attributes such as the year of observation. That information would be very valuable for my research. Would you have any idea why these other attributes are not displaying in QGIS? Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you post your follow-up question as a separate question and mark this question as solved? Maintaining one question per page makes it easier for others to find it when they have a similar issue.